# Query to select and display multiple columns in Google sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, pivot, pivot-table, google-query-language

I have a sheet where I have column of Names, Date, and some other data. Just like Google forms responses are recorded; sheet contains repeated names and dates in few rows but with different data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uNOqyTyA3euPr9tiuUEiNVWMhv_ysEqqd6Yhwez6bhY/edit?usp=sharing

So far I have used query to combine data of a single column like

```
=QUERY({Data!A3:M },"Select Col1, Sum(Col4), sum(Col5), sum(Col6)  Where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by Col1 ")
```

But I want to populate data 1 according to dates!!

Please have a look at my Google sheets 'Query' tab.

Please help me~~

Comment: Is it better to use `pivot table` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pivot it:

```
=QUERY({Data!A3:M },
 "select Col1,sum(Col4),sum(Col5),sum(Col6) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2 order by Col1")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help, also Can you please tell me HOW TO REMOVE the label "sum" beside date .

Comment: @shane sure, try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKOhc.png